# Queries on ROS 2 tutorial

Tags: ros2

I am a beginner, and I am following the ROS 2 tutorial. I have a couple of questions about [this tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html):

- Q1: In line 1, we import `rclpy`, so why do we need to import `Node` separately in line 2?
- Q2: In line 9, we write `self` as the argument of `__init__` function. Can we write anything else instead of `self`? For example, can we define the function as: `def __init__(us):`?
- Q3: In line 10, we give the name `minimal_publisher`. Can I write anything else instead of `minimal_publisher` in line 27? Can I write in line 27: `test_minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()`
- Q4: What will be the name of our node? Is it `MinimalPublisher` or `minimum_publisher`?

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Q1: indeed, I don't think this is necessary. To be sure: try and remove it and see if it still works.

Q2: No, `__init__(self)` is the python equivalent of a constructor. It can have other arguments, but the first one is `self`. `self` is the equivalent of c++ `this`.

Q3: yes, it is just a variable name.

Q4: the node name is `minimal_publisher`, defined in line 10.

My suggestion for you is to read some tutorials on python first (just google, there are many), it'll make you advance much quicker.

Final remark: don't paste code as an image, paste the text in a code block (```), e.g.:

```python

[Code here]

```

which will look like this:

```py
[Code here]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your answers and suggestions.

Comment: I'd add on to the answer here. In Q1, you do not explicitly *NEED* to import `rclpy.node`, when you import `rclpy`, the Node class present in `node.py` should also be loaded. But, then in order to access the Node class, you'd have to do `rclpy.node.Node` every time. By importing the Node class separately from the `rclpy.node` module, you make it easier for you to access the Node class later on. It is also a good practice to import only what you need from any library, instead of doing something like `from rclpy import *`.